# How to use javascript to set text area value in a form in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, text, area

I can use this to set a text area (selectedtext) value in a form (submitquestion) if Firefox, but it fails in IE.

`document.submitquestion.selectedtext.value =  txt;`

Answer (score 15):

This should work:

```
<textarea id="bla">from</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("bla").value = "test";
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
document.forms['submitquestion'].elements['selectedtext'].value = txt;
```

Assuming you have:

```
<form name='submitquestion'>
    <textarea name='selectedtext'></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using JQuery, it works with all browsers.

```
$('#selectedtext').val('whatever');
```

Comment: nothing wrong with using jQuery
you can get the value by $('#selectedtext').val()

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in pure javascript like this

```
document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = txt;
```