# How do I clear an uncontrolled textarea in react.js?

Tags: reactjs

I can get the value just fine using:

```
this.refs.myTextArea.getDOMNode().value
```

Trying to set that does nothing.

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle that demonstrates the problem? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5589101/95190

Comment: `this.refs.myTextArea.getDOMNode().value = ''` works for me. There must be something else interfering in your environment.

Comment: If `value` is set in your JSX, the component will be controlled even if you assign it an empty string. To give a default value and let it stay [uncontrolled](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#uncontrolled-components), use the `defaultValue` attribute instead of the standard `value`.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I'm a jsFiddle n00b, but will try to set one up.

Comment: @glortho definitely tried that in the onKeyPress handler, and it wasn't working. Will try to whittle it down to figure it out...

Comment: @ssorallen it's definitely an uncontrolled component, i.e. no value set. Something else must be going on.

Comment: @rawbee - fork this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/, which just provides the basic React to get you started.

Answer (score 6):

this.refs.myTextArea.getDOMNode().value = "";

Comment: In newer versions of React, `React.findDOMNode(this.refs.myTextArea).value  = ""`

Answer (score 6):

In even newer version of React ( > v15 ), you don't need `findDOMNode()`, `this.refs.myTextArea.value =''` is enough

Answer (score 0):

Is the value of your textarea being bind to a state of your component?

If yes then you can't set value like this, what you should do is call `setState` to change it.

Comment: No, it's definitely an uncontrolled component.